# Java Reflection Beans Property API

Tags: java, reflection, javabeans

Is there any standard way to access Java Bean Property like

```
class A {
   private String name;

   public void setName(String name){
       this.name = name;
   }

   public String getName(){
       return this.name;
   }

}
```

So can I access this java bean property name using Reflection API so that when I change the value of property the methods of getName and setName are called automatically when I set and get values of that property

Answer (score 45, accepted):

What you need is the BeanInfo / Introspector mechanism (see Bozho's answer). However, it's hell to use this directly, so you can use one of the Libraries that offer property-based access. The best-known is probably [Apache Commons / BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils) (another one is Spring's [`BeanWrapper`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans) abstraction)

**Example code:**

```
A someBean = new A();

// access properties as Map
Map<String, Object> properties = BeanUtils.describe(someBean);
properties.set("name","Fred");
BeanUtils.populate(someBean, properties);

// access individual properties
String oldname = BeanUtils.getProperty(someBean,"name");
BeanUtils.setProperty(someBean,"name","Barny");
```

Comment: just for the ignorant (me), why not just call someBean.setName("Fred")?

Comment: @simpatico for a single known property, obviously, yes. But if you want to manage access to many different properties of many different types of Objects, use bean properties

Comment: thank you. I buy it if the properties are set in a file one loads and then just calls BeanUtils.populate(someBean, properties);
But I'd never in practice call set("name", "Fred") while I can call setName("Fred") directly (I no yours is just example code).

Comment: @simpatico: If you've got the type information to know at compile time that there is a `setName` method, that's what you should use. Otherwise, a bean introspector makes life easier as it can reduce a lot of coupling. Moreover, the cost of using introspection isn't actually too high (outside of critical inner loops).

Answer (score 47):

You question is very unclear, but if I get it:

Yes. The `java.beans` package has the so called [`Introspector`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html). There you can read the properties of a bean.

```
BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(Bean.class);
PropertyDescriptor[] pds = info.getPropertyDescriptors();
```

You can find the desired `PropertyDescriptor` by its name and you can call `getReadMethod().invoke(..)`

Comment: I prefer this method because you need no dependencies.

Comment: an other advantage of this way is that the java.lang.reflect.Method can be re-used so that getting/writing the value of the same property on different instances of the same class can be much faster, reading a property is around 100x faster compared to using BeanUtils and 20x Spring BeanWrapper. I like also the answer of perdi-estaquel because of code example

Answer (score 3):

Use a `java.beans.PropertyDescriptor`

In your case:

```
A a = new A();
PropertyDescriptor nameProperty = new PropertyDescriptor("name", A.class);
nameProperty.getWriteMethod().invoke(a, "potato");
System.out.println(nameProperty.getReadMethod().invoke(a));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried BeanUtils as well as PropertyDescriptors because I did not have the information on the class that was passed to my method. I did not even know the data types of the properties passed and so setting values became difficult. I know that BeanUtils should do the conversion automatically for the property and set it but it was not saving the data for me. So finally, I had to rely on getting the fields. Here is what I did:

```
Field[] fields = className.getDeclaredFields();
for (int i=0; i<fields.length ;i++)
{
  String element = fields[i].getName();
  String propertyType = fields[i].getType().getName();
  fields[i].setAccessible(true);
  if(propertyType.equalsIgnoreCase("java.lang.Integer"))
    {
      fields[i].set(mypojoObj, Integer.parseInt(parameterValue));
    }
    else
    {
      fields[i].set(mypojoObj, parameterValue);
    }
 }
```

I did a similar switch-case to convert all property types to correct types. When fetching from the page, request.getParameter(paramname) was always returning String so this conversion worked for me. Any better options for direct data conversion will be really helpful.