# What is a short-hand method for creating a of key/value pairs from a class instance variables?

Tags: java

What should be a best way to create key/value pairs for all the string instance variables of a class? Is there any library exists doing such a task?

I am doing the same using a reflection based backward look-up. But it seems doing to much work.

For example:

I have a class

```
public class Account implements ManagedEntity {

private String accountNumber;

public Account(String accountNumber) {
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
}
}
```

If an instance of `Account` class is created like blelow,
    Account ac = new Account("abc");

The output map should be like: [{"accountNumber", "abc"}].

Comment: What do you need this for? Are you trying to build a Map or a String?

Comment: Building a Map for all properties of the class.

Comment: Seems like he wants to build a map, but the question doesn't make much sense: what will comprise these key/value pairs besides the string instance variable? In other words, you will map what to what?

Comment: @A.R.S Only String values, nothing else.

Comment: So you will map strings to other strings?

Comment: @A.R.S Please make a difference between "The question doesn't make much sense" and "I cannot imagine a use case for what you are trying to achieve".

Comment: Perhaps BeanUtils is what you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856895/java-reflection-beans-property-api

Comment: @Mulmoth I indeed meant the former.

Comment: updated the question to clear it up

Comment: I think that this can be done using `Annotations`, but that too perhaps take as much effort or more as your `reflection` approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Peter Lawrey already pointed out in one of the comments, if you are looking for a library that can do that transformation for you then one possible answer is [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/):

You could use the [`BeanUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html) class from that library:

```
Account account = new Account("abc");
Map accountMap = new HashMap();
BeanUtils.populate(account, accountMap);
```

Or using the [`BeanMap`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanMap.html) implementation it would be even easier:

```
Account account = new Account("abc");
Map accountMap = new BeanMap(account);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned by Peter Lawrey and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856895/java-reflection-beans-property-api), it would be like

```
Account ac = new Account("abc");
Map<String, Object> properties = BeanUtils.describe(ac);
```

To limit it to String properties, you could use a [BeanUtilsBean](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtilsBean.html) instance, passing a subclass of [ConvertUtilsBean](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/ConvertUtilsBean.html) to the constructor. The subclass overrides the [lookup method](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/Converter.html), which returns null if the class isn't `String`.