# Recover attributes from Object variable

Tags: java, object, methods, attributes

So this is the context for my question.

I created a singly linked list whose nodes' attribute is an Object variable so i can store objects from different classes. So far so good.

```
        public class Node 
    {

        Object data;
        Node next;

        public Node(Object data)
        {
            this.data=data;
            this.next=null;
        }

[...]    

}
```

Thing is i don't know how to recover attributes/methods from the stored objects. This one for example.

```
public class Product 
{
    double discount;
    double price;

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

[...]
```

Help.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of different ways you can get these.

Apache provides a nice API , 
[Java Reflection Beans Property API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856895/java-reflection-beans-property-api)

or you can use Java Reflection 
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-java-method-at-runtime/

Answer (score 0):

Another way, if you have a limited number of types of objects that you are storing (or at least plan on retrieving attributes from) is to use `instanceof` and class cast as in

```
if(node.data instanceof Product){
    Product p = (Product) node.data;
    //Get attributes from products
else if(node.data instanceof SomethingElse){
    SomethingElse p = (SomethingElse) node.data;
    //Get attributes from somethingElse
}
...
else{
    //throw an error or ignore the final case
}
```