# How to loop over a Class attributes in Java - from a given list (NOT reflection getDeclaredFields())?

Tags: java

How can I iterate over the attributes of an object, with the attribute names provided in a list/array - **NOT all attributes**, like using reflection & `getDeclaredFields()`.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public type1 att1;
    public type2 att2;
    public type3 att3;

    public MyClass(
        att1="helo";
        att2="bye";
        att3="morning";
    );

    ...
    public void function()
    {
        String myStrings[];
        myStrings = new String[] { "att2", "att3" };

        MyClass myobject = new MyClass();
        for(var in myStrings)
        {
           System.out.println(var);
           System.out.println(myobject.var);
           System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is using reflection not valid?

Comment: using reflection is valid, but I did not want to loop over ALL the fields, rather only specified ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is somewhat ambiguous about using reflection. If you are OK with reflection, but want specific fields only without iterating over `getDeclaredFields()`, then the following code should work for you:

```java
for (String var : myStrings) {
    Field field = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField(var);
    field.setAccessible(true);
    System.out.println(var);
    System.out.println(field.get(myObject));
    System.out.println();
}
```

Note that this code works for private fields, too. Also, keep in mind that you'll have to handle exception associated with the reflection calls.

**UPDATE**: Exceptions thrown in this code.

`MyClass.class.getDeclaredField(var)` declares a checked `NoSuchFieldException`. You must handle it because obviously there is no mechanism to make sure that the fields in `myString` match an actual implementation of `MyClass`.

`field.get(myObject)` throws a checked `IllegalAccessException` if the field is inaccessible. Which it should not be because of `field.setAccessible(true)`, but you still have to catch or re-throw the exception.

There are also unchecked exceptions you may want to handle. See the javadoc for details

- [java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField-java.lang.String-)
- [java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible-boolean-) inherited by `java.lang.reflect.Field`
- [java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: indeed `MyClass.class.getDeclaredField(var);` is what I was after. Could you elaborate on "handle exception associated with the reflection calls." - do you mean if my field name does not exist, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use some technology that builds on top of JavaBeans / BeanInfo. Apache Commons / BeanUtils is a good starting point here.

Please refer to this previous answer of mine for more info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5856982/342852

But if you just want to use fields, not bean properties, here's a Java 8 method to do so:

```
public static Map<String, Object> getFieldProperties(Object o, Collection<String> fields) {
  Class<?> type = o.getClass();
  return fields.stream().map(n -> {
    try {
      return type.getDeclaredField(n);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
  }).collect(Collectors
    .toMap(
      (Function<Field, String>) Field::getName,
      (Function<Field, Object>) field -> {
        try {
          field.setAccessible(true);
          return field.get(o);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
          throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }));
}
```

Unfortunately the checked exceptions make this more verbose than it would need to be.